# Github : I am missing "Settings" menu on the landing page of my repo

Tags: github, webhooks

The "Settings" menu is supposed to be the last menu, just after the "Graphs" menu.

Not having the "Settings" menu interferes with my ability to set Webhooks.

And yes, this is my repo - I own it.

[image: 1]] landing page of my test-repo-travis repo

Comment: Try hitting `Ctrl + F5` or clearing your cookies and cache.

Comment: Well, this happened to me today, I could see the option on my phone but not on my laptop.

Comment: Ask your repository admin to add yourself as a collaborator on that repo by following this guide: [Inviting collaborators](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository).

Comment: Go for the quick fix first. Are you signed-in? Thanks Gigi

Answer (score 42):

I was having the same issue today. Eventually, I figured that I do not have enough permissions to access the repo settings because in my case the repo belongs to an 'organization' and even though I have read/write access to it, I am not the admin.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you're logged in.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ctrl+F5 was ineffective, at least in my case.
2. Clearing the cache and cookies is the nuclear option, and it worked - Although it hurts.
3. I double checked after the fact: the landing page issue I had was specific to my Chrome browser, at least in this case. The landing page, as displayed by my Firefox browser, was fine. Ditto for the Safari browser was fine.

Until today, I'd never heard of a case where a landing page rendering could be fixed by nuking cookies and cache.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me today too, fixed by adding /settings to the repository link

**EDIT**: Notice this will only work, if you are the owner of the repository

Comment: What does this mean, exactly?

Comment: So you have the repository link, something like: https://github.com/<UserName>/<RepositoryName>/

And you want to go the seetings of this repository: 
So u add settings to the link: https://github.com/<UserName>/<RepositoryName>/settings 


Notice this will only work, if you are the owner of the repository, i.e. you have access to the settings but because of some random bug, the settings button doesn't appear

Comment: @XAronX "Notice this will only work, if you are the owner of the repository" - should be a part of your answer

Comment: @AzarEJ true, i forgot that

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me today. It turns out, I wasn't signed into GitHub. As soon as I signed in, the settings have become visible.