# How do I get my GitHub repository settings back in the web?

Tags: github

I want to try and fix my course's repository in GitHub by deleting multiple folders and files. The problem though is that I don't have the settings on my repo for some reason. I want to use the web, not `git-cmd.exe`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972285/github-i-am-missing-settings-menu-on-the-landing-page-of-my-repo) question didn't solve my problem, the settings aren't still there.

Q: **How do I get it back?**

Comment: Did you use [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)? What do you mean with settings?

Comment: Please read again. I said "repository settings".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you are not able to view the **Settings** tab on the repo in GitHub, that means **you are not the repo admin or the organization owner**. Only users with admin access can view the **Settings** tab on a repo in GitHub.

You would need to request for the required permissions with the repo owner to be able to view the **Settings** tab.

Comment: Wait, how do I request? Pull requests don't work obviously.

Comment: By contacting the owner with the contact if present in the owner's profile.